# Как обработать событие нажатия и отпускания ScrollBar в FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу узнать расположение мыши в моменты нажатия и отпускания ScrollBar в FlowLayoutPanel, чтобы создать объект в зависимости от расположения мыши или удалить его же. Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: Свойство [MousePosition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А как мне узнать, что было нажатие на ScrollBar в элементе?